# HTTP request causes java.io.FileNotFoundException

Tags: java, android

Below is the code that makes http request from `doInBackground()` method and for some reason it's throwing `FileNotFoundException`

```
Bitmap icon = null;
String url = "http://abc.xyz.net/com.tatvic.oatest.gif?uv=2.0&ds=Yes&bt=100.0&tis=11.808&ais=5.478&tes=NA&aes=NA&cs=still";

try {
    InputStream in = new java.net.URL(url).openStream();
    icon = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);

} catch (MalformedURLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Another approach I followed is using `HttpURLConnection` as shown below, but same exception still occurs.

```
HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(url).openConnection();
InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
icon = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
```

Stacktrace:

```
12-27 15:19:54.726 31141-31188/com.tatvic.oatest W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://abc.xyz.net/com.tatvic.oatest.gif?uv=2.0&ds=Yes&bt=100.0&tis=11.808&ais=5.478&tes=NA&aes=NA&cs=still
12-27 15:19:54.729 31141-31188/com.tatvic.oatest W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:238)
12-27 15:19:54.729 31141-31188/com.tatvic.oatest W/System.err:     at java.net.URL.openStream(URL.java:470)
12-27 15:19:54.729 31141-31188/com.tatvic.oatest W/System.err:     at com.tatvic.lib.uit.e.a(Unknown Source)
12-27 15:19:54.729 31141-31188/com.tatvic.oatest W/System.err:     at com.tatvic.lib.uit.e.doInBackground(Unknown Source)
12-27 15:19:54.729 31141-31188/com.tatvic.oatest W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:295)
12-27 15:19:54.730 31141-31188/com.tatvic.oatest W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
12-27 15:19:54.730 31141-31188/com.tatvic.oatest W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234)
12-27 15:19:54.730 31141-31188/com.tatvic.oatest W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
12-27 15:19:54.730 31141-31188/com.tatvic.oatest W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
12-27 15:19:54.730 31141-31188/com.tatvic.oatest W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

I am not accessing anything from any filePath even though `FileNotFoundException` occurs. I am catching exception but I have to call that url anyways.

What is the **reason for exception**? How can I **solve** it?

Comment: File does not exist at requested location, check it

Comment: do your url contains images ???

Comment: @USKMobility yeah but what is the location? I am not accessing any file from any location.

Comment: @MeanCoder not images, it contains only one image of 1 pixel.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> What is the reason for exception?

`FileNotFoundException` is only thrown when making a network call if a **404** is thrown by the server. Some bad server implementations throw **404** even if you use a method that is not allowed, that is using GET instead of POST.

> How can I solve it?

You can solve it by hitting the URL from your browser and making sure it actually exists. If it exists you should not get this exception.

Comment: There were *some bad server implementations* causing error. Solved it!

Comment: In my case this error does not occur everytime. It is just random, most of the times it works fine

Comment: How do I prevent this error from being thrown in cases where I still want to get the data from the server?

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem and i just solved it.
In my case, i had
`urlConnection.setChunkedStreamingMode(0);`
and, for some reason, this was causing this problem to show up once every 2 requests. I've removed this line and now it works every time.

I'm leaving this here, just in case someone else has the same problem like mine.

Answer (score 0):

Unsure if anyone else is still having issues but I searched everywhere for the answer to my app login not working. For me it was PHP version on my hosting was set to 8.1 I just downgraded it to 7.4 until I write an updated version login for my app. Now makeHttpRequest(); is working